# Laravel how can make a query string but not like url path?

Tags: laravel, url

I'm trying to make an url query string with laravel but this method:

```
url()->to('categories', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'cars']);
```

Returns me:

```
http://localhost/categories/1/cars
```

But I need this:

```
http://localhost/categories?id=1&name=cars
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll need to create a named route without parameters:

```
Route::get('categories', ['as' => 'categories', 'uses' => 'SomeController@showCategories']);
```

Then use `route()` helper:

```
route('categories', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'cars']);
```

This will generate:

```
'/categories?id=1&name=cars'
```

Comment: No! this function need to have a route on my routes/web.php file. It is not working like this. i have make my router class. Something else?

Comment: For example Route::any(Request::path(), 'Extender@xRun');

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos it's working as expected when you put the route into the `routes.php`, I've just tested it and it creates exactly URL you need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
Route::any(Request::path(), ['as' => Request::path(), 'uses' => 'Extender@xRun']);
```